# What are the values taken by j in the loop

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

What is the behavior of the following line in the class `Sort`?

```
for (int j = i+1; j > ListPerson.size(); j++) {
```

I added `System.out.println(j);` to see the values taken by `j`, but when executing, no value is displayed!
Why does Eclipse not consider `ListPerson.get(j)` as an error, knowing that `j > ListPerson.size()`?!!

```
package Tests;

public class Person {
    String nom;
    int age;

    public Person(String nom, int age) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.age = age;
    }           
}
```

---

```
package Tests;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import CompUnivSol2.Etudiant;

public class Sort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        List<Person> ListPerson = new ArrayList<Person>();  
        ListPerson.add(new Person("Paul", 20));
        ListPerson.add(new Person("Coco", 18));
        ListPerson.add(new Person("Eric", 4));


        String temp1;
        int temp2;
        for (int i = 0; i < ListPerson.size(); i++) {           
            for (int j = i + 1; j > ListPerson.size(); j++) {               
                if (ListPerson.get(i).age > ListPerson.get(j).age) {

                    temp1 = ListPerson.get(j).nom;
                    ListPerson.get(j).nom = ListPerson.get(i).nom;
                    ListPerson.get(i).nom = temp1;

                    temp2 = ListPerson.get(j).age;      
                    ListPerson.get(j).age = ListPerson.get(i).age;
                    ListPerson.get(i).age = temp2;
                }
            }
        } 

        for (int i = 0; i < ListPerson.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print("\n N°" + (i + 1) + ": " + ListPerson.get(i).nom + ": " + ListPerson.get(i).age); //le \n pour mettre chaque
                                                                                //établissement dans 1 ligne
        }
    }
}
```

the last loop in the class `Sort` displays the following:

> N°1: Paul: 20
>
> N°2: Coco: 18
>
> N°3: Eric: 4

Comment: Eclipse can not guess that j>ListPerson.size(), eventhough it is your loop condition.
But the program will never enter the loop because of that condition.

Comment: I added System.out.println(j); to see the values taken by j, but when executing, no value is displayed!
 j>ListPerson.size() is not a problem! that's what I don't understand!
I've modified the class Sort : I added the last loop that displays the persons sorted by age

Comment: Looks that on your problematic line, you have `j >` instead of `j <`.

Comment: the problem that the program is working even if 'j > ListPerson.size()'. When I change it to 'j < '  I get an exception!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `j > ListPerson.size()` in the following line

```
for (int j = i + 1; j > ListPerson.size(); j++)
```

this loop is not getting executed at all.

When `i = 0` -----> `j = 1` -----> the condition gets evaluated as `1 > 3` (i.e. `j > ListPerson.size()`)

As you can understand, `1 > 3` is `false` and therefore the loop does not get executed.

You need to change it to

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < ListPerson.size(); j++)
```

Apart from this problem, your sorting logic is also not correct. Instead of swapping the persons, you are just swapping their names. To fix the problem, replace

```
String temp1;
int temp2;
for (int i = 0; i < ListPerson.size(); i++) {           
    for (int j = i + 1; j > ListPerson.size(); j++) {               
        if (ListPerson.get(i).age > ListPerson.get(j).age) {

            temp1 = ListPerson.get(j).nom;
            ListPerson.get(j).nom = ListPerson.get(i).nom;
            ListPerson.get(i).nom = temp1;

            temp2 = ListPerson.get(j).age;      
            ListPerson.get(j).age = ListPerson.get(i).age;
            ListPerson.get(i).age = temp2;
        }
    }
}
```

with

```
Person temp = null;
for (int i = 0; i < ListPerson.size(); i++) {           
    for (int j = i + 1; j < ListPerson.size(); j++) {  
        if (ListPerson.get(i).age > ListPerson.get(j).age) {
            temp = ListPerson.get(i);
            ListPerson.set(i, ListPerson.get(j));
            ListPerson.set(j, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

However, an elegant way would be to use `Collections.sort` instead of sorting this way.

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.